# Как умножить все элементы массива на 2 без использования операторов (*,/,+)

Tags: c++, c

Как умножить все элементы массива на 2 без использования операторов умножения (`*`), деления (`/`) или сложения (`+`)?

```
void multiplyArrayValue(bool test)
{
    if(test) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizePart; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < countPart; j++)
                cout << parts[j][i] << "\t";
            cout << endl;
        }
    } else  cout << "";
}
```

Comment: `a - (-a)` и даже без скобок должно прокатить

Comment: А тип элементов? Если беззнаковые целые - то  `element <<= 1;`

Comment: смотря что в массиве... parts[j][i] = parts[j][i] << 1 ?

Comment: Если это реальная задача по работе, игнорируйте идиотские требования. Если это олимпиадная задача, решайте её самостоятельно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используй битовые сдвиги (<<) 
x = x<<1 
[документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/336xbhcz.aspx)

Comment: Очень благодарю